# Bot Framework .Net Activity reply = activity.CreateReply(

Tags: bots, reply

Was trying to use the below code to make the bot reply in different locale 
however seems this isn't working, any idea how can this be possible?

```
Activity reply = activity.CreateReply(activity.Text, locale: "de-de");
```